# VBA Monte Carlo Simulation - Repair Time Generator (Lognormally Distributed)

Tags: math, excel, simulation, montecarlo, vba

my name is Rik and I'm a 6-sigma green belt, and I've created a Monte-Carlo Simulation of an Aircraft Engine repair facility. I'm currently doing a 6-sigma project on in Excel VBA.

I simply scaled a random number while I was developing the program, but now that it's developed I'd like to use the inverse lognormal CDF http://engineer.jpl.nasa.gov/practices/at2.pdf to create the random repair times, but I couldn't find the function online.

I did find the below code on http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vba12.htm but it is for the normal distribution and I'm not certain of it's accuracy. I couldn't find an equation for the inverse lognormal CDF.  I'd like similar code for the inverse lognormal CDF function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
'****************************************************************************
'*         Return random numbers from Standard Normal Distribution          *
'****************************************************************************
Function gauss()
    Dim fac As Double, r As Double, V1 As Double, V2 As Double
10      V1 = 2 * Rnd - 1
        V2 = 2 * Rnd - 1
        r = V1 ^ 2 + V2 ^ 2
        If (r >= 1) Then GoTo 10
        fac = Sqr(-2 * Log(r) / r)
        gauss = V2 * fac
End Function
```

Comment: Excel VBA is a pretty awful statistics tool; there are plenty of statistics tools out there that will prevent you from having to reinvent the wheel on tasks like this (and reduce the likelihood of introducing errors). Some are even free (R is a good example).

Comment: You should add the [math] tag to your question to attract the specialists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Excel VBA the Excel function Loginv together with a random number between 0 and 1 can be used to generate a random Log-normally distributed number.